# Devise Token Auth customised routes for additonal endpoints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-6, devise-token-auth

I'm trying to setup custom routes for Devise_Token_Auth for additional endpoints for my User model. Here's my default devise_token_auth routes.

mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'

Now, I want to add routes for some endpoints which are defined in UsersControllers. e.g endpoints are with name:

- signup_email
- verify_mobile_signin
- register_sports_complex

which are post requests. How can I define routes for these additional endpoints which are not already defined in Devise_token_auth controllers.
My UsersController.rb file is in directory custom_users/users_controller.rb.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The gem `devise_token_auth` uses the `devise` gem under the hood. You can define the additional routes using `devise_scope` as you'd do in the actual `devise` gem.

```rb
# config/routes.rb

mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'

devise_scope :user do
  get :route_name,            controller: :your_controller_name
  # or
  get :route_name,            to: 'controller_name#action_name'
end
```

For your case

```rb
# config/routes.rb

mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'

devise_scope :user do
  post :signup_email,            controller: 'custom_users/users_controller'
  post :verify_mobile_signin,    controller: 'custom_users/users_controller'
  post :register_sports_complex, controller: 'custom_users/users_controller'
end
```

Use the appropriate HTTP action verb `GET`, `POST`, `PATCH` etc, depending on your route.

Devise [documentation](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-routes)